# sum and diffrence from two sql table according to item - laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, sum, difference

I'm trying to get the result of the sum of two different tables and find difference of this table: so here are my table

**Orders Table**

[image]

**Ship Table**

[image]

**Table and Query**
[image]

i need to get query result according to item if no quantity then ZERO Tried using ISNULL throws null all values and not result from IFNULL. code or SQL Query Which i have used.

```sql
    select orders.item,
           SUM(orders.quantity) as aQuantity,
           SUM(ship.quantity) AS oQuantity,
           SUM(orders.quantity) - SUM(ship.quantity) AS diffrence
    FROM orders,
         ship
    GROUP BY orders.item
```

**required Output**
[image]

Comment: post your code as  text not as image ....

Comment: OK! Whats the problem now?

Comment: result of the following code gives me result for foods as 60 which should be 45 from both the table and also the diffrence between 1st table and 2nd table or in simple the SUM(quantity) from table one and two with diffrence. and group or arrange according to item

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try:

```
select a.item,IFNULL(o_quant,0) as "o_quant",IFNULL(s_quant,0) as "s_quant",(IFNULL(sum(o_quant),0) - IFNULL(sum(s_quant),0)) as "difference" from (select o.item,sum(o.quantity) "o_quant"
from orders o group by o.item) a left join (select s.item,sum(s.quantity) "s_quant"
from ships s group by s.item) b on a.item = b.item group by a.item,o_quant,s_quant;
```

[image]

Comment: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'

Comment: Replace isnull to IFNULL.
Updated the Ans.

Comment: when i add new item. its not Reflecting

Comment: Its should reflect. What results are you getting?

Comment: if i do it Right Join it will reflect. it depends on which table m using and where m entering data.btw thank you